# Whats the UX strategy behind Twitter's Retweet dialog?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, ux-field

Mouse Hovering over a particular tweet on the feed will show these links - / Reply , Retweet , Fav , More / - 
These links are prominent enough and clean.

I dont understand the reason for (re)confirming the retweet action, by a Retweet dialog.

In case of Touch devices, On click takes us to a screen with that tweet and action elements.

***Is this a good experience for the user ??
What is the UX Strategy behind this ??***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply a "dangerous" action; accidentally retweeting things could potentially send unintended messages to hundreds or thousands of recipients, even if the action is reversible. Additionally retweeting can often be seen as endorsing the opinion/statement in the retweeted tweet.

Note that the "favorite" button doesn't require a confirmation; favorites aren't broadcast nearly as publicly (pretty much only you and the author of the favorited tweet is likely to see it), so it's okay to leave it as a single-press, reversible action.

Comment: Will "Don't show this again" checkbox help ??

Comment: Thanx for ans. But still isnt it a bad UX. Cant this be considered that a tweep will know the value of RT

Comment: Agree, it *should* have the extra "are you sure" step for an action as significant as retweet.  Perhaps some people would think it is not significant enough to require the extra step, but I would wager most people do.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes at using Facebook in my smartphone, when I scroll the screen accidentally click "Like" of photos or messages that I don't wanna...

Maybe Twitter is in the correct.